# Go to last data row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has many pages inside.
How can I go to the last data row quickly when I change the page?
I tried `ctrl+end` but this goes to line 1007. `ctrl+↓` not working either.

Answer (score 1):

If pressing <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> in a column takes you to the very last row of the sheet, rather than the last row that has visible data, chances are that the column contains fill-down formulas or non-blank values.

Note that a cell is not considered truly blank if it contains any whitespace such as a space character or even the zero-length text string `""`.

In the event the column is filled with an array formula at the top of the sheet, you can get truly blank values by using the `iferror(1/0)` pattern instead of `""`.

You may also want to take a look at the [jumpToToday_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32097728?msgid=33126935) script that lets you return to where you were last time you were editing the spreadsheet.